# Get value of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I'm trying to get a return using the date object. 
But I can not and console.log of firebug I see the value you want to use.

I tried to show my image in question

[image]

**I need to get the value returned in the data object Name**

my code (js)

```
$(function () {
            //'use strict';
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                url: '/resource/upfoto2.ashx',
                maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
                dataType: 'json',
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                        $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                    });
                },
                progressall: function (e, data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                        'width',
                        progress + '%'
                    );
                }
            }).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) { $("#progress").show(); })//2
    .bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {  })//3
    .bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {  })//5
    .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {  })//8
    .bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {  })
    .bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {  })//9
    .bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
        console.log(data);
    })//6
    .bind('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {  })//7
    .bind('fileuploadstart', function (e) {

    })//4
    .bind('fileuploadstop', function (e, data) {
        $("#boxCrop").load("/resource/crop.html?r="+Math.random(2));
    })//10 - chama ao terminar de fazer o upload da FOTO
    .bind('fileuploadchange', function (e, data) {  })//1
    .bind('fileuploadpaste', function (e, data) {  })
    .bind('fileuploaddrop', function (e, data) {  })
    .bind('fileuploaddragover', function (e) {  })
    .bind('fileuploadchunksend', function (e, data) {  })
    .bind('fileuploadchunkdone', function (e, data) {  })
    .bind('fileuploadchunkfail', function (e, data) {  })
    .bind('fileuploadchunkalways', function (e, data) {  }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput).parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
        });
```

Comment: How about showing the failing code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to get the value entered in the Name image

Comment: In your question you've stated: "... trying to get a return using the date object." How your last comment is related with that? Show the code with which you've troubles, and explain what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: @Teemu I suspect either Google Translate or just poor English. I submitted an edit suggestion to try and clarify his question.

Comment: you should have drawn those arrows/circles freehand!

Answer (score 2):

According to the code you posted, the issue is the misssing capitaization of `file.Name`

```
done: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<p/>').text(file.Name).appendTo('#files');
    });
},
```

Also, binding empty functions to handlers is like not binding them at all, so I suggest you get rid of any extra handlers you don't/won't actually use. That makes your code to look like this:

```
$(function () {
    //'use strict';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: '/resource/upfoto2.ashx',
            maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.Name).appendTo('#files');
                });
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        }).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
            $("#progress").show();
        })
        .bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .bind('fileuploadstop', function (e, data) {
            $("#boxCrop").load("/resource/crop.html?r=" + Math.random(2));
        })
        .prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput).parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```